# Meteor package installation behind firewall

Tags: meteor, proxy, npm

How are packages like npm-bcrypt and iron router installed? Do they use a custom npm registry? I'm trying to use meteor behind a corporate firewall (so all outbound connections must go through a local http proxy on say port 8080). I can install npm packages fine because I can configure the proxies in the .npmrc file, and I can turn off strict-ssl. However, it seems like meteor ignores the npmrc file. Is there any way to turn off ssl and have the package installation use a proxy?

```
=> Started proxy.
=> Errors prevented startup:

   While downloading npm-bcrypt@0.7.7...:
   error: SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN

   While downloading iron:core@0.3.4...:
   error: SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN

   While downloading iron:dynamic-template@0.4.1...:
   error: SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN

   While downloading iron:router@0.9.4...:
   error: SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN

   While downloading iron:layout@0.4.1...:
   error: SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN

=> Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.
=> Started MongoDB.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `HTTP_PROXY` and `HTTPS_PROXY` environment variables to use meteor behind a corporate firewall.

From https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Using-Meteor-behind-a-proxy

Examples:

on Linux or Mac OS X export

```
HTTP_PROXY=http://user:password@1.2.3.4:5678 export
HTTPS_PROXY=http://user:password@1.2.3.4:5678 meteor update
```

on Windows

```
SET HTTP_PROXY=http://user:password@1.2.3.4:5678 SET
HTTPS_PROXY=http://user:password@1.2.3.4:5678 meteor update
```

Comment: This blocks `DDP`: `"Error: Invalid protocol: proxy.cora.eu.int: at Object.Future.wait ....`
So makes meteor useless

Comment: @DotNetWise no it doesn't. You have another issue. The proxt is meant for packages and doesn't involve client side/server side facing DDP

Answer (score -1):

There is a big discussion on Meteor's GitHub for this: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2515

I would recommend posting in there so that core devs can respond.